# allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled:timeout:) deprecated

Tags: ios, swift, location, updates, core-location

I am using Xcode 15.3 with Swift 5.
I would like to defer location updates in CLLocationManager.
I googled and found this method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates
However this is flagged as DEPRECATED.

I would like to know if there is a new method which is supported by Apple where I can set a time out which delays the call to **didUpdateLocations**.

Does anyone know if there is a replacement for **allowDeferredLocationUpdates** method?

Comment: Significant location change monitoring is the closest replacement. I don't think deferred location updates ever worked particularly well since they require that the gps chip is enabled there were no real power saving benefits and added complexity.

Comment: does `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` work for you ?